# Need Help in table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Add Function is working only.

When you input something and hit add button each time you will see lists.

I want the select button's innerHTML as select and unselect when toggled. When the select button is selected a remove button will appear at the right side of the select button otherwise the remove button will not appear.

Can you do this with scope attribute and tbody tag and let me know the work of scope attribute and tbody tag.

Also I want to edit selected lists.

If a select button is selected edit button will become visible in the form. Add some code in edit function so that I can edit selected list with new input with the input fields.

nth-child's(even and odd) color of the lists should be different in the table as it shown with css. That need to be done in javascript so that when I remove a list it don't match with it's upper or lower list's color(nth-child(even and odd)).

And add some code to remove all list in remove function.

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}

#b1 {
  outline: none;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#b2 {
  outline: none;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

#Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 600px;
}

#Form {
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#fname {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 0.1px solid green;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#lname {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 0.1px solid green;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#age {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 0.1px solid green;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

button[type=button] {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #353535;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

tr {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

tr:first-child {
  background: #153535;
  color: white;
}

tr:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

<body>
  <table id="Table" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form name="myForm" id="Form">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Last Name" name="lname" id="lname" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Age" name="age" id="age" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove All</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    function check() {
      var isEmpty = false;
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
      if (fname == "") {
        alert("Enter First Name.");
        isEmpty = true;
      } else if (lname == "") {
        alert("Enter Last Name.");
        isEmpty = true;
      } else if (age == "") {
        alert("Enter Age.");
        isEmpty = true;
      }
      return isEmpty;
    }

    function select() {
      var i;
      var table = document.getElementById("Table");
      for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
          document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
          age = document.getElementById("age").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
          var rindex = this.rowIndex;
          console.log(rindex);
        }
      }
    }
    select();

    function add() {
      if (!check()) {
        var i;
        var table = document.getElementById("Table");
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("age").value = "";

        var insrow = table.insertRow(table.length);
        var cell1 = insrow.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = insrow.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = insrow.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = insrow.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = insrow.insertCell(4);

        var b1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        b1.innerHTML = "SELECT";
        b1.setAttribute("id", "b1");

        var b2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        b2.innerHTML = "REMOVE";
        b2.setAttribute("id", "b2");
        b2.addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
        });

        cell1.innerHTML = fname;
        cell2.innerHTML = lname;
        cell3.innerHTML = age;
        cell4.appendChild(b1);
        cell5.appendChild(b2);
      }
      select();
    }

    function edit() {
      var table = document.getElementById("Table");
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    }

    function remove() {

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its a bit confusing exactly what you want, you have a lot of text describing multiple parts and its hard to follow.